# Plotting K-means

Tags: r, k-means

I am plotting K-means as showed below:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggfortify)
newdf <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean))
set.seed(1)
autoplot(kmeans(newdf, 3), data = newdf)
```

It throws me an error:

```
Error in do_one(nmeth) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
In addition: Warning message:
In storage.mode(x) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: You are passing the "Species" column to `kmeans` and that column is non-numeric. There's no obvious way to calculate distance for such a variable. Is that your intention? What exactly did you want to happen here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kindly change the levels of a factor to '0','1' etc . depending on number of factor levels.

then you can avoid the error